# Comapring rule between two variables in rules not working in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am doing a function to change the users password. Inside of the **Users** model I have create three variable like the following.

```
public $oldPassword;
public $newPassword;
public $repatePassword;
```

Now I need to compare newPassword and repare password together and i added the followinf rule inside of the model.

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('username, password', 'required'),
        array('username', 'length', 'max'=>20),
        array('password', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('oldPassword', 'findPassword', 'on' => 'changePwd'),
        //array('repatePassword','compare','compareAttribute'=>'newPassword', 'on'=>'changePwd'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, username, password', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

I have the following form.

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Old Password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'oldPassword',array('size'=>20,'maxlength'=>20)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'oldPassword'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'New Password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'newPassword',array('maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'newPassword'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Repate Password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'repatePassword',array('maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'repatePassword'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Update'); ?>
    </div>
```

Now when I exactly put the exc same values in both of the fields it still gives me that the values are not the same. Why is this?

Comment: Show your complete `rules()` method. `newPassword` must have a rule for itself in order to be declared safe and be assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following rule to your `rules()` method.

```
array('oldPassword,newPassword,repatePassword','required','on'=>'changePwd')
```

Without a rule for an attribute, that attribute will NOT be massively assigned to the model and so will not be available for any validation.

Alternately, you can change `required` to be `safe` if you just want to allow assignment, and not make the attributes actually required, although in this case `required` makes sense to me.

Based on your rules, the reason it says they do not match is because `newPassword` is not being assigned, and so is an empty string being compared to your intended password.

Comment: Hello, this fixed all of my problems. Thank you for your help and i didn't know.